# Excel file name with wildcard

Tags: python

I am trying to work with Excel workbooks in Python.

I need to assign a workbook to a variable, but workbook name in the variable needs to have a wild character as any time the code will execute, the name of the source workbook will be different (start of it will be the same).

For example:

Name of source workbook will be "Report One.xlsx" and each time it will change to "Report Two.xlsx", "Report Three.xlsx" etc.

So I want to have a variable, let's say:

```
reportData = "Report*.xlsx"
```

Then I check that with:

```
testOutput = pd.read_excel(dataFile)
testOutput.head()
```

But it doesn't work that way unfortunately so it seems like there should be another way (it works only if I assign the full name).

I've tried to look in to the other similar topics but I either didn't find the one I need or didn't understand the solution.

Comment: Use `glob.glob()` to get the filenames matching a wildcard.

Comment: you mean to wrap a file name in it so it would be: 

reportData = glob.glob("Report*.xlsx")
?

Comment: That will return a list of all the matches. If you know there's only one, use `[0]` to get it. Otherwise, iterate over all of them.

Comment: Yeah, there will only be one file in same directory at a time. I am trying different variations, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you tell me how should that line of code look like? (Also, I am using Python3 and installed glob3, is that correct?)

Comment: `reportData = glob.glob("Report*.xlsx")[0]`

Comment: I don't think you need to install anything, it's a standard module.

Comment: Ah, that's where that [0] had to go to :-) Yeah, that worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help! So many more things to do now, I am happy to have this one behind!